# enter to submit for different forms in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

hello  i have created the both popup sign in form (in menu) and search box 
i have already set enter to submit action for signin form using this code in codebehind

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSignIn.UniqueID
```

and now i want to set enter to submit action also for search box i have tried same way as sign in form using

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSearch.UniqueID
```

but both button are conflicting any one only works please guide me for how make both working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found answer i just palced the search box and button into the panel control then set the property of pannel like this

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" defaultbutton="btnSearch" >
```